# convert text to number with leading zeros

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I would like to know if there is an easier way to change various length text in a column to a fixed length number format with leading zeros.
I export data out of a custom program into EXCEL .. it comes in as a .txt file.
There is a column of data with numbers like
1627
23456
1658
567896
I would like to make them all the same length with leading zeros so they can then be compared to other info.

My goal is to not have to add columns then sort then CONCATONATE based on manually adding the proper number of zeros into one of the concatonate cells ....

HELP :-)

Comment: Does this sound good? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910495/excel-convert-mass-text-to-a-number-and-maintain-fixed-length

Answer (score 3):

Highlight the column and go to Format>>Cells. Choose "Custom" and put in the following: `000000#` You could also do this in a second column by using the formula `=Text(A1, "000000#")`

Comment: I have done this in the past but it does not help in actually changing the raw data ... which is something I need to reference in another sheet that has brought data from a different program and is stored as general with the leading zeros ... so I incur a mismatch when referencing one and looking up info in the other (sheets that is).  Not sure if this helped provide greater clarity to the question.

Comment: If you are looking up info from another sheet, then use the `Text(A1, "000000#")` in the comparison. `Vlookup(Text(A1, "000000#"), 'Other Sheet'!A1:B50, 2, false)` for instance... or the reverse if looking up on the other sheet `Vlookup(0 + A1, 'This Sheet'!A1:B50, 2, false)`. In other words, just force the format in whatever formula you are using to compare or lookup.